# TensorFlow why we still use tf.name_scope when we already have the function tf.variable_scope

Tags: python, tensorflow

I do not understand why we also need the function `tf.name_scope` when we already have `tf.variable_scope`. From the Tensorflow official API, I see that the `tf.variable_scope` is more powerful because it can have an effect on `tf.get_variable`. When we create layers and want to share variables, we always use `tf.variable_scope` and `tf.name_scope`. However, I try to learn something new from code released by Nvidia on GitHub. I found that it is frequent for coders to use `tf.name_scope`. Why do we still need this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.variable_scope` to add a prefix on **both** variables created with `tf.get_variable` and operations: as you said, this allows also variable sharing but it also makes the first call to `tf.get_variable` the definition of new variable under this scope.

`tf.name_scope` adds a prefix **only** at the operations: variables defined outside the `tf.name_scope` using `tf.get_variable` are not prefixed thus the `tf.name_scope` is ignored completely for this variable: you're not declarning a variable prefixed in any way.

This can be useful when you want to create an operation block (using `tf.name_scope`) that uses a variable declared outside of it. This variable can be even used by multiple operation blocks at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation first. Could you please give me an example? I am still confused about the application of "tf.name_scope" you described. Thank you so much!